# Why does g++ states, that there is "no matching function for call cbegin(o)" for some valarray<double> o?

Tags: c++, g++, c++14

Please consider the following code:

```
using custom_t = std::valarray<unsigned>;
custom_t o;
unsigned acc = std::accumulate(std::cbegin(o), std::cend(o), 0);
```

g++-5 says

> No matching function for call to `cbegin(custom_t&)`

If I use `std::begin(o)` and `std::end(o)` instead, everything works. Is this a compiler bug? The code compiles with Visual Studio 2015.

Comment: [Compiles in libc++.](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e78b7b445c344d4f) I think that libstdc++ is implementing some kind of SFINAE for types that satisfy the Container concept. Since `std::valarray` is not a Container, the call fails.

Answer (score 3):

This is a libstdc++ bug, I've just created https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=67374

Comment: It doesn't make any sense to me, why `std::begin` and `std::end` are specialized for `std::valarray`, but `std::cbegin` and `std::cend` are not. What's the reason?

Comment: @0xbadf00d the reason is probably noone thought of doing or even specifying that. Which kind of makes sense, considering valarray is meant to be rather lightweight and not so feature-rich. I must admit I've never used valarray myself, because no library I know can actually make use of the additional aliasing restrictions (is there anything else preferable about valarray?)

Comment: *"and so doesn't support all the non-member functions for accessing containers."*, I'm wondering why 1. there is non-member function `std::begin` overloaded for a `const` `valarray`, 2. a template function `std::cbegin` from `<iterator>` is not picked

Comment: I wouldn't be asking without [checking](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/nk9hVzRrwfrSwGkl)

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki, it's because `<valarray>` includes `<iterator>` before defining the `begin` and `end` overloads for valarrays, so they aren't visible to `cbegin` and can't be called. Which looks like a bug.

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki, bug report created, thanks for making me take a proper look